# Technique for saying the title of the text

Tags: literary-techniques

Is there a technique for when the title of the text is explicitly mentioned. For example; Cersei Lannister says "In the game of thrones, you win or you die", even in the 5th season of G.O.T. a dance of dragons is also explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Are you asking if 'game of thrones' should be emphasised? Surely the text is named after the quote - not the other way around. Could you explain what you *think* should be done?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK That's not what he is asking. See [my answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/270647/55623).

Comment: No offence but I prefer to hear from the person who asked the question.

Comment: Remember that in Cersei's context, when she says "game of thrones" she's not saying a title, she's just making clever use of words.

Comment: @Jim Yes, I imagine that's the point. She's just making clever use of words, but from a beyond-the-4th-wall perspective, those clever words also happen to be the title of the work (and from a writer's perspective, that's not coincidental). OP wants to know the name of this phenomenon.

Comment: What is the significance of the quote, "In the Game of Thrones, you win or you die. There is no middle ground" 

Would you say that it is adumbration?

Comment: It's just plain old everyday foreshadowing, the fundamental ordering technique of everything from Oedipus Tyrannos to a shaggy dog story to Wittgenstein's Tractatus to Wagner's Ring to a relative clause: you estabish some gap in the audience's understanding and some time later you fill in the blank and the audience says "Oh, *now* I get it." Ka-chunk.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; this technique is known as a ***title drop***¹.

[From TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TitleDrop), for example:

> ### Title Drop
>
> If a line of dialogue is the title of the episode, movie, or book, it obviously must have some great significance.
>
> *Michael*: Your average American male is stuck in a perpetual state of adolescence, you know, arrested development.
>
> *Narrator*: Hey! That's the name of the show!
>
> — *Arrested Development*

That article also explicitly lists your quote as an example of a *title drop* under the [heading of "live action TV](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/TitleDrop/LiveActionTV)":

> In *Game of Thrones*, every episode is Title Dropped since the episodes are typically named after a significant line from them, and the titles aren't displayed.
>
> However, the one that tops them all is a series title drop and episode title drop in one line:
>
> *Cersei Lannister*: When you play the game of thrones, you win... or you die. There is no middle ground.

TVTropes also offers *name drop* as an alternative title, but because that is a well-established term outside of film and theater circles, with [a different meaning](https://www.wordnik.com/words/name-drop), it's probably best to stick with the descriptive, direct, *title drop*.

¹ <sub>Which is either straightforward or unimaginative, depending on your perspective. But in either case it gets the idea across.</sub>

Comment: But how is that "a technique ***for saying*** a title" - That's what it's called ***when you use the title in dialog***, but a technique requires some steps:  If you want to say the name of the show in dialog, you can first xxxx and then yyyy...

Comment: @Jim I don't think OP was using terminology as precisely as you are. From what I can glean from his question, he was using *technique* to mean *trope*: in other words, he's asking (AFAICT) *what do you call it when...?* It can't be a coincidence that OP's precise example is listed on this trope's page.